# I dont understand a problem im having with an toString while mixing it with my UI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, overriding, tostring

I have a SuperClass and two subclasses.
This two subclasses are used on my ui when i click on a button. I want to create one Estudiante and put it on a list. Estudiante has a lot of attributes inside it so i have toString methods on the subclasses and on the superclass.
I have edited the properties of the setListData so a string is no longer required. The problem is, now when i run the program and i try to add an Estudiante and show it, it gives me the StackOverflowError on the lines of the toString of the subclass and the superclass. I would really appreaciate if someone could try to fix it with my code. Thanks

I havent tried much, i have only changed the method for setting the list in the past but now theorically its fixed.

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    private int numero;
    private int semestre;

    public Estudiante(String unNombre, int unaCedula, String unMail, int unNumero, int unSemestre) {
        super(unNombre,unaCedula,unMail);
        this.setNumero(unNumero);
        this.setSemestre(unSemestre);
    }
```

The toString() of Estudiante (I didnt posted the get and set methods because i dont think they mattered)

````
@Override

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "Numero:" + this.getNumero() + "Semestre: " + this.getSemestre();
    }
    ```
````

SUPERCLASS TOSTRING (Persona)

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        return toString() + "Nombre"+ this.getNombre() + "Cedula " + this.getCedula() + "Mail " + this.getMail();
    }

    public Persona(String unNombre, int unaCedula, String unMail){
        this.setNombre(unNombre);
        this.setCedula(unaCedula);
        this.setMail(unMail);
    }
```

This is what i have on the UI

```
private void BotonCrearEstudianteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        Estudiante unEst=new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante.getText(), Integer.parseInt(CedulaEstudiante.getText()),MailEstudiante.getText(), Integer.parseInt(NumeroEstudiante.getText()), Integer.parseInt(SemestreEstudiante.getText()));
        modelo.agregarEstudiante(unEst);
        ListaEstudiantesJ.setListData(modelo.getListaEstudiantes().toArray());
```

StackOverflowError on the lines of both toStrings, the one on the subclass and the one in the superclass.

Comment: and where exactly are the calls to the `toString()` methods of yours ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
public String toString(){
    return toString()
        + "Nombre"+ getNombre() + "Cedula " + getCedula() + "Mail " + getMail();
}
```

calls the overriden toString:

```
public String toString(){
    return super.toString()
        + "Numero:" + getNumero() + "Semestre: " + getSemestre();
}
```

which again calls the original toString.

Hence and endless loop.

In the base class there are two possiblities:

Only super.toString() is correct:

```
public String toString(){
    return super.toString()
        + "Nombre"+ getNombre() + "Cedula " + getCedula() + "Mail " + getMail();
}
```

Or simply no toString at all.

```
public String toString(){
    return "Nombre"+ getNombre() + "Cedula " + getCedula() + "Mail " + getMail();
}
```